# How to limit file type to be upload in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, file, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom page template with a form, that any visitor of the website can upload a file. Now, I want to restrict the file type that will be upload (docx, doc and pdf only) and I limit the file size into 2MB only.

How to do this? I already have a function that the user allowed to upload, but I don't know how to restrict the file type that allowed to be upload. Please help me.

**Limiting the file is now working, but it's weird why the file is still save even the file is too large. How to fix this?**

PHP in custom page template

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $firstName = isset($_POST['firstName']) ? $_POST['firstName'] : '';
    $middleName = isset($_POST['middleName']) ? $_POST['middleName'] : '';
    $lastName = isset($_POST['lastName']) ? $_POST['lastName'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $mobile = isset($_POST['mobile']) ? $_POST['mobile'] : '';
    $locations = isset($_POST['locations_list']) ? $_POST['locations_list'] : '';
    $position = isset($_POST['position']) ? $_POST['position'] : '';
    $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';
        if( ! empty($_FILES)){
            $file=$_FILES['file'];
            $attachment_id = upload_user_file($file);
        }

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 1048576){
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
        }
}
```

PHP in functions.php

```
function upload_user_file($file = array()){
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
      $file_return = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));
      if(isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])){
          return false;
      } else {
          $filename = $file_return['file'];
          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );

          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_return['url']);

          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $filename);
          wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);

          if(0 < intval($attachment_id)){
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: This may prove to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file

Comment: i don't want to use the client side to limit the file type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by checking the file MIME type and SIZE of the file which is uploading , you can able to restrict the size based on file type

[To check the file type you refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php)

[To check the file size before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514166/check-file-size-before-upload)

if you google it you can get more solutions

Comment: i tried to change the array `'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type']` into this `'post_mime_type' => 'application/msword,vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,pdf'` but still it upload the img

Comment: [Check the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639610/only-allow-certain-files-types-to-be-added-during-an-upload?answertab=active#tab-top)


REF
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

Comment: please see my updated post. Regarding on limiting file size

Comment: You did a mistake on if loop 

refer this 


https://gist.github.com/sureshamk/d68ee3708897b34be20ff86f097b7c51

Comment: can you help me to fix it?

Comment: the file is still saving

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113108/discussion-between-suresh-and-user014019).